# VS 2003 CrystalReports - details section issue

Tags: crystal-reports, visual-studio-2003

I have 2 detail sections on my report (details a and details b).
Fields in both sections can grow up to 10 lines.

How do I force the Crystal Report to print both sections on one page?
Currently the report on bottom page print section "details a", but section "details b" prints on next page. 
How do I prevent this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You does not need an extra group. You can set on the detail area (node over the sections) the flag keep together.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution.
Add new group section (empty) and mark Keep together on this group. :)